# facebook like box stream height

Tags: facebook, stream, height, facebook-like

How to control the facebook like box ***stream part height*** alone. Its normal to reduce height of whole box but if tries to control it *fans images* are not shown.

The css `.fan_box .page_stream{ ...,width:300px}` to `.fan_box .page_stream{...,width:150px}`

i'm asking because the stream box inside iframe

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this one, I'm still looking for a solution. Tried jQuery but it won't work because it's in an iframe. Tried passing in a css parameter with a height to the element as some other fb: elements have this feature but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to change the height. Facebook doesn't provide a way to change the height and there isn't a way to change the height using JavaScript and CSS.

### Why can't I do it with JavaScript and CSS?

CSS just doesn't apply through an iFrame because thats how an iFrame works -- its basically a window to another page with its own CSS.

Javascript won't allow you to access the content of an iFrame if the URL of the iFrame is different than the page that contains the iFrame. Doing:

```
document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow.document
```

Will give you the following warning in Chrome.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL... Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

The reason for this is to prevent XSS. Here's more on the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

I saw this on the Like Box page and figured I'd respond that you can use the 'data-height' attribute:

```
data-height="250"
```

Worked for me. Here's my example:

http://www.skonet.com/Resources/Articles/Index.aspx

Comment: This is only able to shorten the data height. It appears the max data height is somewhere around 300 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

you can reduce the height of the encasing div, hide its overflow and if you want push the top of it underneath an absolutely positioned element with a higher z-index like so:

```
<div style="position:absolute;z-index:2;top:0;left:0;width:300px;height:130px;background-color:#c0c;opacity:0.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50);-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";"></div>
<div style="height:140px;width:140px;overflow:hidden;background-color:#0c0; margin-top: 60px;color: #fff;padding: 30px;font-family:arial;">
    facebook like box goes here - only the green part will be visible if you make the pink box white and take out the 0.5 opacity and the bottom will get cut off so you can just display whatever part you want
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you guys still need it and this is the most acurate trick I can provide and its also promising to work with the every day changing of the facebook like box by facebook.

Its a bit tricky but will work for you guys..

create two seprate like box of the same page, and close them in seprate div right in my case

```
<div class="up1">
facbook like box 1 code
<div class="up2">
facbook like box 2 code
```

Now in the css

use position absolute to class up1

```
.up1 {
position:absolute;
z-index:99999;
background-color:white;
}
```

and in up2

```
.up2 {
    padding-top:87px;
    }
```

What it does it will put the box 1 over the box 2 hiding its facebook like and bla bla making it feel like you have one box that contain picture and streaming of your desired lenght

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around cos I had a problem like this one. Facebook has no standard way of customizing the stream if the faces and header are checked.

The solution is to take them differently. If you need the stream as long as 1000px, just uncheck everything except the stream. This will change its height from the default 300px to whatever value you type in the height field.

See an example below:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MadeinHeavenEvents" data-width="800" data-height="2000" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

Then if you still need the one with faces, get a new code and set the height differently, then uncheck the others. Below is an example:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MadeinHeavenEvents" data-width="800" data-height="500" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

Don't forget to add the SDK before these codes.

I know it's a long time since this was posted, but here is the solution that helped me today

Answer (score 0):

Yes the data-height to 250 will work as it reduce the outside iframe

Now try to set data-height to 1000 - it is still **300px** height,

because the inner div inside the iframe hard coded to 300px and 
you can not control that as it is in a cross domain iframe...

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/example" data-width="292" data-height="250" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
```

Adjust the `height` in this code to what works best for you.