# changing the appearence of an facebook like button (XFBML)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, xfbml

I'm interested if anyone knows how to alter a FB like button that's created with a code like

<fb:like href="ttt" send="false" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
that STILL SHOWS FACES, but can move it's actual literals elsewhere (like more the "reccomend to your friends" to left or right etc.
Has anyone so far been able to manipulate these things, the row breaks, the side of the string, etc?

Answer (score 2):

This relates to this question: [facebook like box stream height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483311/facebook-like-box-stream-height/6960066#6960066)

In short: **No**, you cannot style social plugins because they are contained in an iframe when rendered. See the above answer for more details. Sorry.